# Where does mount API implemented in Linux source code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am newbie for Linux kernel, I cloned the Linux source from its repo on GitHub. I cannot find the file `sys/mount.h` nor the `mount` function.

Do you know where is this file located in source code? Where can I find its implementation?

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.18/source/fs/mount.h

Comment: @stark but there is no POSIX version of mount function defined in this file?

Comment: @stark I assume there should be a POSIX version mount call this real_mount?

Comment: `sys/mount.h` and the `mount` function are part of libc. In the kernel, the `__NR_mount` system call is handled in "fs/namespace.c" (`SYSCALL_DEFINE5(mount,`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know where a system call is implemented in the kernel, there's a general sequence of steps you can use to find it. You will need to download the kernel source to your machine.

Begin by finding the number of parameters the syscall requires. eg. [mount(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) requires five parameters.

Since mount(2) requires 5 parameters, search for `SYSCALL_DEFINE5(mount` in the kernel source:

```sh
grep -nr 'SYSCALL_DEFINE5(mount'
```

This will take a while to run, but it will eventually find:

```
./fs/compat.c:92:COMPAT_SYSCALL_DEFINE5(mount, const char __user *, dev_name,
./fs/namespace.c:3026:SYSCALL_DEFINE5(mount, char __user *, dev_name, char __user *, dir_name,
```

So, the syscall you're looking for is located at in ./fs/namespace.c on line 3026. (I'm using Linux 4.19.99, so the line number will probably be different on your kernel.)